# Best way to synchronize an embedded SQLite database with a centralized database with Codename One

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, synchronization, codenameone

My goal is to achieve a bidirectional synchronization between a SQLite database on smartphone and a central MySQL database hosted on an Ubuntu server. I use the Codename One framework for the client side. Has someone already implemented a mechanism like this?

Comment: There are a lot of strategies for database replication but none are builtin to the sqlite support. You can implement this manually with one of the common strategies.